# An answer I provided has been edited and approved. Do I need to do anything?

Tags: support, editing, answers

An edit has been made to my answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/73779/25656). It has already been approved by Jorge Castro and I agree with the edits. Do I need to do anything more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. If you disagree with the edit, you can, of course do a rollback. But you don't need to do anything.